# How to add a new org in HyperledgerFabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I follow this site: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-add-an-organization-to-your-hyperledger-fabric-blockchain/index.html . And I had some problem at section 4. the section 4 said that, I should add a new org json content ( that is Org3MSP ). But the doc didn't mention how to generate the `json` content. especially there are some string which look like a pem.

[image: Didn't mention how to get the Org3MSP string]
[image: Expand the json]

Comment: this video works. it tells every step! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DKuGU5CYV_E

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for v1.1.x has been updated to add a tutorial for [reconfiguring](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/v1.1.0-alpha/channel_update.html) an existing Hyperledger Fabric blockchain network (the "build your first network" sample network) to add a new organization and peer to an existing channel.

The general flow will be to:

1. set up a `configtxlator` server to interact with the config block of
   the channel
2. fetch the config block using `peer channel fetch`
   command
3. translate the retrieved config block from protobuf to json
   using `configtxlator` server
4. modify the json configuration to
   include the new org's info
5. encode the json into protobuf using
   `configtxlator`
6. compute the delta of the new config and the original in the channel
7. decode the delta config update from protobuf to json
8. wrap that json update in an envelope
9. encode the resulting json into protobuf again, using `configtxlator`
10. sign the transaction for a sufficient subset of the channel's membership to satisfy its endorsement policy
11. submit the signed channel update command with `peer channel update` command
12. fetch the genesis block for the channel with `peer channel fetch`
13. start the new org's peer(s)
14. join the new org's peer(s) to the channel using the genesis block with `peer channel join`
15. install the chaincode to the new org's peer(s) as needed
16. upgrade the chaincode to set a new endorsement policy including the new organization

Yes, it is a bit involved, but we expect that much of this will be automated and simplified for the administrator over time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update configtx.yaml and crypto-config.yaml file. Once you edit you have to runn cryptogen tool to generated related certificates.