# Admit a new member to an existing consortium in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

So I have a consortium with three members -> A, B, C and an orderer in a separate org. I want to admit a new member, D, into the group. The top of the config looks a bit like this:

```
Profiles:
    Genesis:
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Orderer
        Consortiums:
            AllMember-Consortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *A
                    - *B
                    - *C
```

For a number of reasons, each member that transacts with another does so on their own dedicated channel - so we have channels AB, AC, BC defined. An example again follows. This is all working just fine.

```
A-B-Channel:
    Consortium: AB-Consortium
    Application:
        <<: *ApplicationDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *A
            - *B
```

My issue comes when I want to expand the group. If can find a way to admit D - **which is the thrust of this question because I can't seem to find any way to do so** - I need to create new channels for D -> AD, BD, CD. I can do that fairly easily if D is in the consortium, but until D is admitted it's no go.

**I've seen the tutorials allowing you to add a member to a channel, but those seem to require the member to already be in the consortium. I want to admit someone new.**

I tried pretty much everything I could think of with no success, ranging from trying to modify the genesis channel, through regenerating the cryto and restarting the orderer and haven't managed to get anywhere.

1. Has anyone anywhere done this?
2. If so how?

Surely it can't be that strange a requirement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a new org in HyperledgerFabric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47564555/how-to-add-a-new-org-in-hyperledgerfabric)

Comment: No it isn't. Sigh. That is binding a new org to a channel that already exists. This is adding an org to the consortium then creating multiple channels bound to that org.

Answer (score 4):

So while it's bad form to answer one's own questions, this is the top google search for adding an org to a consortium in hyperledger and the solution isn't straightforward.

I can't take credit for actually coming up with them but these instructions:

https://github.com/rohitadivi/Reconfigure-BYFN/blob/master/Create_channel.md

allow you to update the system channel and add a new organization.